# jQuery Dialog: How to scroll/jump to top/bottom/#link in the dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I've a page with links like this:

```
<a href="#link-1">Link 1</a>
```

OnClick it jumps to:

```
<a href="" name="link-1">Link 1 Topic</a> 
Text...
<a href="#top">top</a>
```

Everything works fine but now I want to display the content of that page in a jQuery dialog.

Problem: onClick (top/bottom/#link) the whole page jumps but I only want the content withhin the dialog to jump.

Any ideas how to fix it simple without too much JS? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need the scroll method. Html is not able toscroll the bar you want

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I chose a solution without JS :-)

Comment: Sorry I just noticed I misunderstood your question, my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution:

```
<a href="" name="_top"></a>
<a href="#_top">top</a>
```

**Notice**: the "_" before "top"!